# Get current user while using SQL Authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, active-directory, sql-authentication

We are using a SQL Login as a vehicle for issuing permissions, but once authenticated through SQL, we'd still like to know the Active Directory name of the connected user?

We've tried:

```sql
SELECT SUSER_NAME()
SELECT SUSER_SNAME()
SELECT SUSER_SID()
SELECT USER_NAME()
SELECT USER_ID()
SELECT SYSTEM_USER
SELECT SESSION_USER
SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
```

Is that information still available somewhere?

**Note**: This is different from how to [get windows user login name from sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25629000/1366033) since we're using *SQL Login*, not a *Windows Login* to connect to SQL Server

Comment: Unless you are using Windows Authentication there is no way you are going to be able to retrieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this is **not possible**.

According to [Andrew Barber's comment on "Get windows user login name from sql server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25629000/#comment40043473_25629000):

> If they are logged in as a SQL Server user, they are *not* logged in as a Windows user; no Windows credentials are passed at all; so you simply can't get that information directly