# MSAccess App connecting via SQL user but gather windows user information

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

Hello I have an msaccess app that's connecting to a database using their windows account.
I want to switch this to use a sql user instead.  Problem is I have some triggers on tables that log
the windows user that is updating the table.  Anyway to switch to using a sql user for connecting to the database, but still pull the network user name?  Thinking no but thought I would ask.

Tried switching to sql user but no longer see windows user in some table for auditing

Comment: What is your trigger logic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get windows user login name from sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629000/get-windows-user-login-name-from-sql-server)

Comment: I don't think you can do it if you use sql login, unless you pass the info some other way. For example you could use the programname TDS setting and put the windows username there. You could create separate sql login for every user as well, but that kinda sucks too.